# How to use dash argument in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I am porting a script from bash to PowerShell, and I would like to keep the same support for argument parsing in both. In the bash, one of the possible arguments is `--` and I want to also detect that argument in PowerShell. However, nothing I've tried so far has worked. I cannot define it as an argument like `param($-)` as that causes a compile error. Also, if I decide to completely forego PowerShell argument processing, and just use `$args` everything appears good, but when I run the function, the `--` argument is missing.

```bsh
Function Test-Function {
    Write-Host $args
}

Test-Function -- -args go -here # Prints "-args go -here"
```

I know about `$PSBoundParameters` as well, but the value isn't there, because I can't bind a parameter named `$-`. Are there any other mechanisms here that I can try, or any solution?

For a bit more context, note that me using PowerShell is a side effect. This isn't expected to be used as a normal PowerShell command, I have also written a batch wrapper around this, but the logic of the wrapper is more complex than I wanted to write in batch, so the batch wrapper just calls the PowerShell function, which then does the more complex processing.

Comment: You could have a variable or parameter called something like *-params* if you refer to it as *${-params}*, however, I still don't think you'd be able to pass in the double-hyphen parameter to the function.

Comment: That works, but requires modification of the commandline parameter, which I would like to avoid. I guess I can detect `--` being passed in to the batch script, and then escape it in batch to `--

Comment: Using the backtick "Test-Function `-- -args go -here" works for me

Comment: So, while there is great information in this thread, I ended up just writing a small wrapper in C#, and deploying an exe wrapper, rather than a convoluted batch->powershell->myprogram setup. This was kind of an xy problem anyways, but the answers were still interesting, and can hopefully help someone else in the future! Doing it this way also bypasses some of the other problems I was running into, such as how to deal with quote characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an aside: PowerShell allows a surprising range of variable names, but you have to enclose them in `{...}` in order for them to be recognized; that is, `${-}` technically works, but it doesn't solve your problem.

The challenge is that **PowerShell quietly *strips* `--` from the list of arguments** - and **the only way to *preserve* that token is you precede it with the PSv3+ [stop-parsing symbol, `--%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing)**, which, however, **fundamentally changes how the arguments are passed** and is obviously an extra requirement, which is what you're trying to avoid.

Your best bet is to try - suboptimal - **workarounds**:

- Option A: In your batch-file wrapper, translate `--` to a special argument that PowerShell *does* preserve and pass it instead; the PowerShell script will then have to re-translate that special argument to `--`.
- Option B: Perform custom argument parsing in PowerShell:

You can analyze `$MyInvocation.Line`, which contains the raw command line that invoked your script, and look for the presence of `--` there.

Getting this right and making it robust is nontrivial, however.
Here's a *reasonably* robust approach:

```
# Don't use `param()` or `$args` - instead, do your own argument parsing:

# Extract the argument list from the invocation command line.
$argList = ($MyInvocation.Line -replace ('^.*' + [regex]::Escape($MyInvocation.InvocationName)) -split '[;|]')[0].Trim()

# Use Invoke-Expression with a Write-Output call to parse the raw argument list,
# performing evaluation and splitting it into an array:
$customArgs = if ($argList) { @(Invoke-Expression "Write-Output -- $argList") } else { @() }

# Print the resulting arguments array for verification:
$i = 0
$customArgs | % { "Arg #$((++$i)): [$_]" }
```

Note:

- There are undoubtedly edge cases where the argument list may not be correctly extracted or where the re-evaluation of the raw arguments causes side effect, but for the majority of cases - especially when called from *outside* PowerShell - this should do.
- While useful here, [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

If your script is named `foo.ps1` and you invoked it as `./foo.ps1 -- -args go -here`, you'd see the following output:

```
Arg #1: [--]
Arg #2: [-args]
Arg #3: [go]
Arg #4: [-here]
```

Comment: This is great! Something like $MyInvocation.Line was exactly what I was hoping for! In my case, I don't mind a bit more complexity in the powershell, and I have a fairly limited use case anyways, because I still do have the ability to do a bit of processing in batch and in the underlying program that ultimately the powershell calls.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do so, but instead of double-hyphen you have to pass 3 of them.

This is a simple function, you can change the code as you want:

```
function Test-Hyphen {
    param(
        ${-}
    )
    if (${-}) {
        write-host "You used triple-hyphen"
    } else {
        write-host "You didn't use triple-hyphen"
    }
}
```

**Sample 1**

`Test-Hyphen`

**Output**

`You didn't use triple-hyphen`

**Sample 2**

`Test-Hyphen ---`

**Output**

`You used triple-hyphen`

Comment: That's really weird that it requires 3 dashes. But this would still require a change in the input parameters, which is what I'm trying to avoid. If there isn't a way, I'd rather just use a normal named parameter in that case. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: `---`, unlike `--`, isn't special to PowerShell, so it is passed like any other string-literal argument; the name of the parameter is then incidental (no need to name it `${-}`).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution, which works well also inside pipelines multi-line expressions. I am using the PowerShell Parser to parse the invocation expression string (while ignoring any incomplete tokens, which might be present at the end of `$MyInfocation.Line` value) and then `Invoke-Expression` with `Write-Output` to get the actual argument values:

```
# Parse the whole invocation line
$code = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($MyInvocation.Line.Substring($MyInvocation.OffsetInLine - 1), [ref]$null, [ref]$null)
# Find our invocation expression without redirections
$myline = $code.Find({$args[0].CommandElements}, $true).CommandElements | % { $_.ToString() } | Join-String -Separator ' '
# Get the argument values
$command, $arguments = Invoke-Expression ('Write-Output -- ' + $myline)
# Fine-tune arguments to be always an array
if ( $arguments -is [string] ) { $arguments = @($arguments) }
if ( $arguments -eq $null ) { $arguments = @() }
```

Please be aware that the original values in the function call are reevaluated in `Invoke-Expression`, so any local variables might shadow values of the actual arguments. Because of that, you can also use this (almost) one-liner at the top of your function, which prevents the pollution of local variables:

```
# Parse arguments
$command, $arguments = Invoke-Expression ('Write-Output -- ' + ([System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($MyInvocation.Line.Substring($MyInvocation.OffsetInLine - 1), [ref]$null, [ref]$null).Find({$args[0].CommandElements}, $true).CommandElements | % { $_.ToString() } | Join-String -Separator ' '))
# Fine-tune arguments to be always an array
if ( $arguments -is [string] ) { $arguments = @($arguments) }
if ( $arguments -eq $null ) { $arguments = @() }
```